# Override CKAN validators

Tags: python, validation, ckan

When a new registers a user in CKAN, the chosen password is validated with this function (among others)

```
def user_password_validator(key, data, errors, context):
```

And the main validation part of that function is

```
...
elif len(value) < 4:
    errors[('password',)].append(_('Your password must be 4 characters or longer'))
...
```

I want to extend/override this function (to have a minimum of 8 characters) since I don't want to edit the core code. I've tried to extend `ckan.plugins.interfaces.IValidators` but that doesn't seem to override existing validators, just add new ones.

Any suggestions how to do this? Do I really need to override the entire `user_create` in the `ckan.plugins.interfaces.IAuthFunctions` interface for such a small change?

Comment: Didn't solve this, we added a Javascript validator on the page instead. Would be nice with better server validation as well though